# Recursively mapping file paths in one folder to another folder

Tags: php, regex, data-structures, language-agnostic, filesystems

Let's say I have a folder *`(folder_1)`* with the following structure:

```
/folder_1
  /dir_1
     - file_1_1.txt
     - file_1_2.txt
  /dir_2
     - file_2_1.txt
     /dir_2_1
       - file_2_1_1.txt
  - file_1.txt
```

Now, let's say I have another folder *`(folder_2)`* with the following structure:

```
/folder_2
  /dir_1
     - file_1_1.txt
     - default.txt
  /dir_2
     - file_2_1.txt
     - default.txt
  - default.txt
```

I need to map every file in *folder_1* to a file in *folder_2* such that:

1. `/folder_1/dir_1/file_1_1.txt` maps to  `/folder_2/dir_1/file_1_1.txt`.
2. `/folder_1/dir_1/file_1_1.txt` maps to `/folder_2/dir_1/default.txt`
3. `/folder_1/dir_2/file_2_1.txt` maps to `/folder_2/dir_2/file_2_1.txt`
4. `/folder_1/dir_2/dir_2_1/file_2_1_1.txt` maps to `/folder_2/dir_2/default.txt`
5. `/folder_1/file_1.txt` maps to `/folder_2/default.txt`

I am not the best communicator, so hopefully, the above pattern makes sense to you guys. The question is language agnostic really, but an answer in PHP and/or Javascript would be really great.

So far, I was able to accomplish this in PHP using FileIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, and a bunch of custom classes that extract and then map the path to the files one by one.

This makes me wonder if I am missing an easier way to do this simple mapping. Maybe using regex named groups or something?

**Edit: **

Is it possible that for each file (file path) in *folder_1*, we use a regex pattern to find (reduce) the best match out of a map of all file paths in *folder_2*?

**Further edit:**

This is for mapping data files in *folder_1* to template files in *folder_2*. If for a file in *folder_1*, an exact matching file path (including filename) in *folder_2* is not found, we look for `default.txt`. If `default.txt` is not found, then we move up a directory and use that parent directory's `default.txt`. This way, we keep moving up directory levels till we find the first `default.txt`.

Comment: I don't think there's a magic way to do that. If you want to know if you current code could be improved, you should show it (and if it is an already working code, you should post it on codereview instead of stackoverflow).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks! I added an edit, to explain what I had in mind. I am not really good with using regex patterns (named groups etc) and so need help with that. I know for sure there is a way to do this.

Comment: Not sure that regexes are useful here.

Comment: How do you determine that `/folder_1/dir_1/file_1_1.txt` maps to `/folder_2/dir_1/default.txt`? This is not at all obvious. Are you simply trying to map the file names as they appear. Do you want to map identically named files in each directory and then randomly map those that don't match? You say that this is a "simple mapping." If it's simple, then explain the rules. Because to me the rules when names don't match seem arbitrary. And without well-defined rules, we can't help you with the mapping.

Comment: @JimMischel: remove the root folder ("folder_1" and "folder_2"), check if the path (from "folder_1") exists in "folder_2", If not, map to "default.txt". It isn't difficult.

Comment: If it's that easy, what's the problem? The rules you just described are trivially simple. Just scan the entire folder2 tree, and create a hash table with the names. Then scan folder1, looking up each name in the hash table. If found, remove the name from the hash. Not found, look for default txt. You don't say what happens if there are different numbers of files.

Comment: _I am not really good with using regex patterns (named groups etc) and so need help with that. I know for sure there is a way to do this._ How can you _know for sure_ if you're _not really good_?

Comment: @Armali, we are going a bit off topic but here we go. :) [How I know](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95220/is-a-programmers-gut-instinct-an-acceptable-answer-with-regard-to-design-decisi)

Comment: @JimMischel, I understand what you are saying about creating a hash. But not sure if it is that straightforward. Could you please explain in pseudo-code (C# will work too)? The number of files do not matter. In fact, please check the new edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use your recursive directory scanner to scan all of the `folder_2` directory tree. Build a hash table that contains the file names, without the `folder_2` prefix. So your hash table would contain:

```
/dir_1
/dir_1/file_1_1.txt
/dir_1/default.txt
/dir_2/file_2_1.txt
/dir_2/default.txt
/default.txt
```

Now, start scanning `folder_1`. When you get a file, strip `folder_1` from the front, and look for the resulting string in the hash table. If it's there, then you have a match.

If the file is not there, replace the last segment with "default.txt", and try again. So, when you begin scanning `folder_1`, you get:

```
/folder_1/dir_1/file_1_1.txt
```

You look up `dir_1/file_1_1.txt` in the hash table and find it. You have a match.

Next, you get `/folder_1/dir_1/file_1_2.txt`. You look up `/dir_1/file_1_2.txt` in the hash table and don't find it. So you replace `file_1_2.txt` with `default.txt`, giving you `/dir_1/default.txt`. You look that up in the hash table, find it, and you have a match.

Now, if `/dir_1/default.txt` did not exist, then you would again adjust the file name to remove the last directory. That is, you'd remove `/dir_1`, and you'd look up `/default.txt` in the hash table.

In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
for each file in folder_1
    name = strip `/folder_1` from the name
    if name in hash table then
        match found
        continue (next file)
    end if
    replace file name (everything after the last '/') with "default.txt"
    do
        if name in hash table then
            match found
            continue (next file)
        end if
        remove the last slash, and everything between it and the previous slash.
        (so "/dir_1/default.txt" becomes "/default.txt")
    while name.length > 0

    // if you get here, no match was found
end for
```